# Dynamics NAV Control Add-in not found

Tags: c#, .net, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-nav, dynamics-nav-2013

I'm trying to create a Hello-World control add-in for Microsoft dynamics NAV 2013 R2 (My specific version is 7.10.36836). I'm using this tutorial [http://blogs.msdn.com/b/nav/archive/2013/11/03/creating-your-first-hello-world-control-add-in-for-the-web-client.aspx?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed:%20MicrosoftDynamicsNavTeamBlog%20(Microsoft%20Dynamics%20NAV%20Team%20Blog)](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/nav/archive/2013/11/03/creating-your-first-hello-world-control-add-in-for-the-web-client.aspx?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed%3a%20MicrosoftDynamicsNavTeamBlog%20%28Microsoft%20Dynamics%20NAV%20Team%20Blog%29)

Now the problem is that after registering my HelloWorld.dll file with Control add-ins page (this is simply entering the name and the public key), when I try to launch my custom page in which that HelloWorld should pop-up it says "Could not locate control add-in library for..".

Is there something more in registering the control add-in with Dynamics NAV 2013 R2 than simply entering name and public key - am I missing something here? or is it MS bug (because NAV 2013 R2 has a lot of them already).

I've tried this HelloWorld sample targeting .NET 3.5, 4.0, 4.5 none works.

Also I should mention that this is not for the web client but for pure simple RTC client residing in PC rather than in a browser.

Comment: Did you copy dll to add-in folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was in tutorials C# code. The NAV couldn't see my .dll because `ControlAddInExport` attribute and the whole `interface` were wrapped in "Class".